# Issue with the command exec on php

Tags: php, xml, cmd, exec

I've an issue while using exec on php, maybe I didn't understand how it works.

The problem is: I wanna execute a binary file named 'test.exe'. That program takes data from an input file 'input.xml' and create an new file 'output.xml' with some modification on those data.

The below command line works perfectly on windows cmd :

```
>cd C:\Test
>test.exe C:\XML\example.xml C:\XML\example.out.xml
```

But a php script like this :

```
exec('C://Test//test.exe C://XML//example.xml C://XML//example.out.xml');
```

Doesn't work like suspected;

Each time I get beside the empty generated file example.out.xml another file named gmon.out.

I don't know what kind of file it is. Is it possible that this file will be the source of my problem?

Any idea?

Comment: By script you mean running in the browser?  Probably the user that runs the webserver doesn't have permission to access the input file or create the output file.  Also, in single quotes I don't think you need the double backslash and you can use `/` on windows instead of `\\` anyway.

Comment: but its windows, doesn't every one have  permission to do everything ;)

Comment: @Dagon: Hard to tell.  Malicious code, trojans, viruses etc do, but not everthing.

Comment: @AbraCadaver yeah in the browser. Ok both of them generate an empty file

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong slash, you should be using a double backslash (one to be printed, and another to escape it). Using `//` will be literally translated to `//` so PHP will try to find `C://Test//test.exe` and fail.

The corrected syntax would be either

```
exec('C:\\Test\\test.exe C:\\XML\\example.xml C:\\XML\\example.out.xml');
```

or

```
exec('C:/Test/test.exe C:/XML/example.xml C:/XML/example.out.xml');
```

Comment: I tried both of them but the problem still the same the output is created but still empty no data inside o_O!

Comment: Perhaps whatever web server you're running (Apache, NGINX, Litespeed, lighttpd) does not have access to those files, make sure they're in a folder that the server can access.

Comment: @ AlphaDelta How to make sure that Apache have full access to those files? I use Wampserver on Windows

Comment: I think the best bet would be to put them in C:\wamp\www\